# using Serial Ports in C# Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, arduino, windows-8.1

I'm fairly new to C#, and I'm currently working on integrating an Arduino Uno with a Kinect for Windows sensor. I'm building on someone else's work migrating the environment to a Windows 8.1 App, and to the new Kinect sensors released in 2014. I've looked everywhere else on how to integrate serial communication into Windows 8.1 apps, but it appears that it hasn't been done before, or the functionality has not been added to Windows 8.1, evidenced by the error I get when I attempt to add the System.IO.Ports library. So my question is whether this can be worked around or not. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, .NET v4.6, and the target platform is x86. Any more information can be provided on request. Thank you so much!

**EDIT on 10/08/15 at 14:03:** I've figured out that if I can write a Windows Forms Arduino COM interface and call that from within the 8.1 App when the serial ports need to be initialized or written to, it might work. Am I addressing this correctly? It would be great to know if this was the right way to approach it. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the error in question?

Comment: Well, for starters I get "The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)", and whenever I declare a serial port for the Arduino, I get "The type or namespace name 'SerialPort' cannot be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)". Consequently, anything else Arduino-related is highlighted as an error. I also don't have an Arduino with me so I can't see if it will change if I plug one in.

Comment: A modern UI program requires using the WinRT api layer.  WinRT was an opportunity to cut some dead wood from the traditional winapi.  The kind that cause a lot of trouble, especially to users.  Serial ports were on the top of that list.  You have use a project template that targets a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically right, you have to create three apps, win8.1, proxy and serial handler. The resulting app won't be allowed in the windows store.

Here is an example [app](http://ioi.solutions/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/SerialPortSampleApp.zip)

Excellent How To [here](http://ioi.solutions/serial-port-access-metro-style-app/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like what I just might need. The app I'm designing is for a specific application and I don't intend to make it available to the Store. But the SDK's I've been using for Kinect and such required the use of the Store format... at least that's what I imagined. Now that I think about it, there might have been a way to do that in Forms format, but it will basically require rewriting the whole thing in Forms, wouldn't it? Forgive my terminology; my background is more mechatronics than software development.

Comment: I can't answer that. The connect stuff didn't seem so complicated when I looked at it but even simple things can become complicated with enough code :)